Product of nth roots of unity
Let $\alpha^t$, $t=0,1,2, ..., n-1$ be the $n$th roots of unity
Then their product should be,
$1×\alpha×\alpha^2×\alpha^3×...×\alpha^{n-1}$
$= \alpha^{\dfrac{n(n-1)}{2}}$
$ = [\cos\dfrac{2\pi}{n}+i\sin\dfrac{2\pi}{n}]^{\dfrac{n(n-1)}{2}}$
$= [\cos{2\pi}+i\sin{2\pi}]^{\dfrac{n-1}{2}}$
$= [\cos\dfrac{(2\pi)k+2\pi}{2}+i\sin\dfrac{(2\pi)k+2\pi}{2}]^{n-1}, k=0,1$
$= (-1)^{n-1}, k=0$
$(1)^{n-1}, k=1$
But the answer for k=0 is the only answer why is that?
I know that both can't be the answer but I don't know why I am getting both answers

The product of the roots of a polynomial $p(x)$ of degree $n$ is $(-1)^np(0)$. The $n$th roots of unity are the roots of $x^n-1$ and so their product is $(-1)^n(-1)$.

I am also aware about this derivation but I am in doubt with the derivation using complex numbers

De Moivre's theorem (which you are using to bring the powers inside the trig terms) is only valid for integer powers. So the step where you bring in $\frac 12$ is definitely invalid reasoning. But moreover, in the complex numbers, $z^{ab}$ does not necessarily equal $(z^a)^b$ (although this is true for $a, b$ integers.) For example, $$ -1 = -1^1 = -1^{2/2} \neq (-1^2)^{1/2} = 1^{1/2} = 1. $$ So even bringing in $n$ without $(n-1)/2$ is a mistake. The correct way to proceed is $$\left(\cos \frac{2\pi}n + i \sin \frac{2\pi}n\right)^\frac{n(n+1)}2 = \left(\cos \pi(n+1) + i \sin \pi(n+1)\right) = (\cos \pi + i \sin \pi)^{n+1} = (-1)^{n+1}.$$
(If you are interested as to why this is the case I suggest looking into the complex logarithm, definition of power for non-integers in $\mathbb{C}$, multifunctions and branch cuts etc.)

But I had studied how to use de moivre 's theorem for fractions in power from internet. And it said I had to use it as I have done above, similar to how nth roots of unity are derived. So is that wrong?

@yyzr It requires care. As you have done, you're solving for all $w$ such that $w^2 = z$. But that's not a valid square root function as it has multiple outputs, so we don't define $z^{1/2}$ like that. The critical error is in assuming $z^{n(n+1)/2} = (z^n)^{(n+1)/2}$. As shown in my first example this can lead to incorrect conclusions.

Let $m=\dfrac{n(n-1)}{2}$.
If $n$ is odd, then $n=2t+1$ and so $m=nt$. Therefore, $\alpha^m=(\alpha^n)^t=1$.
If $n$ is even, then $n=2t$ and so $m=t(n-1)=tn-t$. Therefore,
$$
\alpha^m=\frac{\alpha^{tn}}{\alpha^{t}}=\frac{1}{\alpha^{n/2}}=-1
$$
